# C# modulo operator

Tags: c#, math, modulo

Just recently I stumbled upon a problem using the (what I assumed to be modulo) operator `%`:

[image]

Basically `(-1) % 5` returns `-1` instead of `4`, so `%` seems to return the remainder instead of the mathematically correct modulus (either that or Wolfram Alpha is bad at math).

My question is quite simple:
Is there a ***real*** modulo operator in C# that I don't know of? Or do I have to write my own code for that?

All results I can find in the internet only point to the `%` ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modulo operation with negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720656/modulo-operation-with-negative-numbers)

Comment: [_"The **remainder** operator `%` computes the remainder after dividing its left-hand operand by its right-hand operand"_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) -- (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Strikegently Thanks, I guess this work-around will work. So the answer is that there isn't an existing, build-in method for it?

Comment: @Strikegently that question is about C, not C#. See also [% (mod) explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10065080/995714), [Why does the % operator sometimes output positive and sometimes negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42661964/995714), [How does modulus differ in C# vs. Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35393745/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no modulo operator in c#.

The `%` operator,  is the remainder operator:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-

> The remainder operator % computes the remainder after dividing its left-hand operand by its right-hand operand.